# Create loop for with json in python

Tags: python

I have json and I want print all value and description. But I can't deal with the loop, please help

```
print(d1[0])
```

Result:

ack

total

...

```
print(d1[0]['ack'])
```

Result:

20

I want print d1[0]

print(f"ack: {d1[0]['ack']}")

print(f"total: {d1[0]['total']}")

...

but using loop for ()

```
for d in d1[0]:

    print(f'{d}: ? ')
```

Comment: _"I have json..."_ - Please provide a [mre] and the output you expect your program to display.

Comment: `for key, val in d1[0].items(): print(f'{key}: {val}')`

Comment: Next time please ask with proper formatting, and including all code parts and when possible a minimal example as @TedLyngmo suggest.

Comment: It doesn't look like you have JSON. IT looks like a Python data structure that might have been read from a file in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand it correclty you would to something like this, iterating with key and values. Learn Python Dict because json in python is just a Dict.

```
for key, value in d1[0].items():
    print(f"{key}: {value}")
```